# C++ : Checking for palindrome in LinkedList - recursive method - error

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to find palindromes in a given linked list by recursively going down to the last node in the list and comparing the first node with the last node in the list.

My LinkedList has standard Nodes with an int value member and a pointer to the next node.

I'm passing a pointer to the head node pointer as the first parameter and changing it to the next with each successful match, but I'm getting an error in the syntax. Can someone explain why I'm getting this error?

Code snippet:

```
bool isPalindromeRecur(Node** left, Node* right){
            if(right == nullptr) return true;
            bool isP = isPalindromeRecur(left,right->next);
            if(!isP) return false;
            bool isP1 = (*(left)->val == right->val);
            *left = *(left)->next;
            return isP1;
        }
```

I am getting errors at lines 5 and 6.

```
error: request for member 'val' in '* left', which is of pointer type 'Node*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
             bool isP1 = (*(left)->val == right->val);
                                   ^~~
error: request for member 'next' in '* left', which is of pointer type 'Node*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
             *left = *(left)->next;
                              ^~~~
```

Comment: `bool isP1 = (*(left)->val == right->val);` -> `bool isP1 = (*left)->val == right->val;` and `*left = *(left)->next;` -> `*left = (*left)->next;`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `(*left)->...` instead of `*(left)->...` in both the lines. The `->` operator has higher preference than the `*` operator and so `*(left)->next` will be parsed as `*(left->next)`. Since `left` is of type `Node **`, this will be like trying to access `next` member of a pointer.

Comment: I voted to close as a typo, but if anyone is going to answer, they should explain what the difference is and why the change is required.

Comment: Yeah, it was a silly typo on my part. Thanks for pointing it out, I somehow missed it during multiple revisions.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive call should be under all required conditions.
Your first condition is wrong and not strong enough to be fallowed by recursive call.

Also first argument `Node** left` type is an overkill. This kind of argument is useful when you need to modify list (insert or remove items).

```cpp
bool isPalindromeRecur(Node* left, Node* right) {
    assert(left);
    assert(right);
    if (left == right) return true; // for odd length
    if (left->value != right->value) return false;
    if (left->next == right) return true; // for even length
    return isPalindromeRecur(left->next, right->prev);
}
```

if your list is not double linked then this is much harder to do.

Comment: Yeah, would've been easier with a doubly-linked list. I was trying it out with a singly-linked list in order to test the logic I found on GFG. Thanks for your help!